# querying posts by custom taxonomy terms right from a querystring based URL

Tags: custom-taxonomy, wp-query

The following URL seems to work for cats and tags only.

`yoursite.com?cat=2&tag=bread1+bread2`

what if you wanted to get into custom taxonomy and terms and do something similar?

is there an equivalent to something like the following?

`yoursite.com?taxonomy=food&tag=bread1+bread2`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This should work :

```
  yoursite.com/taxonomyname/bread1,bread2
```

So for example, on my site, I actually use :

```
 mysite.com/location/barcelona,paris
```

And I get a list of all posts tagged with Barcelona or Paris

Comment: Thank you barakadam, I was also given this solution in the wp-hackers list -> yoursite.com?food=bread1+bread2 orfor your particular case mysite.com/?location=barcelona,paris